# How to represent categorical variable vs Continuous variable using ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have to plot   categorical variable `flag` having values `Y` and `N` against continuous variable `Weight` . Which is best kind of plot?

```
qplot(x=Data$Weight, geom="histogram", main = "Weight distribution for Y Goods", binwidth = 0.5, xlab = "Weight of Y Goods", fill=I("blue"), col=I("red"), alpha=I(0.2), xlim=c(0,5))
```

Comment: Homework questions should not be asked in here. There is a ton of material present on the internet detailing, types of graphs suitable for plotting categorical vs continuous variables. Did you even try to find it out?

Comment: @Ashish,First of  all I am not student.

Comment: plot1 = qplot(x=Data$Weight,
      geom="histogram",
      main = "Weight distribution for Residential Goods", 
      binwidth = 0.5,
      xlab = "Weight of Residential Goods",  
      fill=I("blue"), 
      col=I("red"), 
      alpha=I(0.2),
      xlim=c(0,5))
 But I am not able combine both.

Comment: your question lacked "research effort". You got to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand why your question was downvoted. Continuing further, I suggest you edit your question to include the code which is now in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `fill = Data$Buy_Flag` so your plot code looks like this:

```
qplot(
  x = Data$Weight,
  fill = Data$Buy_Flag,
  geom = "histogram",
  main = "Weight distribution for Y Goods",
  binwidth = 0.5,
  xlab = "Weight of Y Goods",
  fill = I("blue"),
  col = I("red"),
  alpha = I(0.2),
  xlim = c(0, 5)
)
```

and your graph looks like this:

[image]